# Is there a difference in meaning between these two phrases?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjective-phrases

First phrase

> Computer speed-up and repair

Second phrase

> Speed-up and repair of computer

Is there a difference in meaning between these two phrases? **Which of these phrases is more suitable for the sentence:**

> I offer ___________________.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Of those two, I would recommend using the first one.

> I offer computer speed-up and repair

Footnote: If you wanted to use the second one, use the plural.

> I offer speed-up and repair of **computers**

(I still think the first one sounds better, though.)

Fun fact: When a noun is used as an adjective (as it does in the expression *computer repair*), that is called a **noun adjunct**. You can read more about noun adjuncts on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: Well explained, thank you! Additional question - How about "Slow computer speed up and repair" versus "Speed up and repair of a slow computer?". Does your answer stay the same?

Comment: My choice would depend on context. Is this for a pamphlet? A business card? An ad in the Yellow Pages? A street sign? A résumé? A Help Wanted ad? Also, you might want to wait a little longer before accepting an answer (see [this](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)).

Comment: Thank you for the link, I just learned something new :)) Context? Hmm. Business card, portfolio. I speed up and repair computers, but only the slow computers. I need to use the "Slow" word to make it clear that the repairs are only about repairing the slowness.

Comment: _I can speed up your slow computer_.

Comment: Yea I could totally leave out the "Repair" word. I want to include it because of the keyword preferences. To me, "Slow computer speed up and repairs" could mean both "I will speed up and repair your slow computer" or "I will speed up and repair your computer slowly". Former is what I want to achieve.